# Какой правильный подход работы с полями объектного типа в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, vue.js, объекты

У меня есть:

backend на Spring, т.е. на Java

frontend на VueJS, т.е. на JavaScript

В Java соответственно у объектов есть поля, которые имеют объектный тип данных(классы). При передаче этих объектов на клиент, в JavaScript, какой подход по работе с такими полями будет правильным?

На клиенте для таких полей мне в основном нужны только id и title объектов являющихся значениями этих полей.

Преобразовывать поля-Объекты Java так же в поля-объекты в JavaScript, например:

```
{
id: 1,
title: "Наименование 1",
field: {
    id: 1.1,
    title: "Наименование 1.1",
    other: ""
}
otherfield: "",
}
```

Либо, объекты преобразовывать в поля примитивных типов, например:

```
{
id: 1,
title: "Наименование 1",
id_field: 1.1,
title_field: "Наименование 1.1",
otherfield: "",
}
```

Comment: для фронта, JSON идеально подходит

Comment: Оба подхода правильные. Тут дело вкуса. Для удобства, чтобы не скидывать лишние поля на фронт, можно посмотреть в сторону библиотеки [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org) или ей подобных